# login/signup 'too many redirects' error

Tags: php, redirect

I'm getting this annoying error which I can't seem to get rid of.

Relevant snippets:

**index.php:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']) && $_SESSION['isLoggedIn']===true){
    $isLoggedIn = true;
}else{
    $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = false;
    header('Location: /signup');
}
```

**signup.php:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']) && $_SESSION['isLoggedIn']===true){
    header('Location: /');
} else {
    $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = false;
}
```

I get redirected to `signup.php` page, but after that get `too many redirects` error. In server logs, there are just `302` redirects to `signup.php` page. I'm not redirecting anywhere else in `signup.php`.

Where could this error come from?

Comment: Do you have other `header('Location...` anywhere in your code? (Maybe in an included page)

Comment: Try commenting the header's one by one, and see if the error disappears. Your code looks code though.

Comment: @user3593846 - did that, without any success.

Comment: @Fred -ii-'s (now deleted) comment suggested to change `signup` to `signup.php`, and it worked! Only proves I still have a long way to go. :)

Comment: ah I see @tekina so it was a typo after all. Wasn't sure about it, so I deleted my comment about it. I revisited the question to see what was happening with it.

Comment: Maybe you have an htaccess that is making a redirection to `index.php`, which then redirects to `/signup`, that falls again in the htaccess redirection rule, creating a loop.

Comment: @FirstOne I deleted my comment about what I mentioned to the OP earlier. `header('Location: /signup');` to `header('Location: /signup.php');` and adding `exit;` after each header. The error may also stem from .htaccess as you mention, so it's looping like crazy.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hm.. I see. I was just thinking that since the op said they just added the `.php`, something seemed off. That **alone** shouldn't cause a redirection loop. Anyways, it's fixed... I doubt the op cares anymore xD

Comment: @FirstOne it's hard to say for sure but it's a likely scenario. Might even be triggered by a 404 and wants to redirect over and over and to an (non-existant) index file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `header('Location: /signup');` is failing because the file is actually called `signup.php` and `/signup` is a folder.

and is interpreted as: `/go_to_root/signup/index.php`

Since that folder doesn't exist, it's looping over from a most likely 404 and to an index file.

Therefore, you need to make it read as

```
header('Location: /signup.php');
```

and add `exit;` after each header, otherwise, your code will continue to execute.